# how to fix 403 error in google authentication at xamarin forms for accessing web resources at Android app

Tags: xamarin.forms

thanks in advance.....

i got this error while connecting to my app with azure cloud via google authentication

"403. that's an error. error: disallowed _useragent this user- agent is not permitted to make on oauth authorization request to google as it is calssified as an embedded user- agent per our policy ,only browsers are permitted to make authorization request to google. we offer several libraries and samples for native apps to perform authorization request in the browser."

how to fix this error.....

Answer (score 0):

This happens from last year because of a change in Google's security policy. The work around is to use Xamarin.Auth and use Interceptors in the native codes to catch the Authentication process. A good example is available in this following link [Xamarin Authentication](https://timothelariviere.com/2017/09/01/authenticate-users-through-google-with-xamarin-auth/)

```
class ActivityCustomUrlSchemeInterceptor : Activity
{
    protected override void OnCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        base.OnCreate(savedInstanceState);

        /* global::Android.Net.Uri uri_android = Intent.Data;

        //#if DEBUG
        //  System.Text.StringBuilder sb = new System.Text.StringBuilder();
        //  sb.AppendLine("ActivityCustomUrlSchemeInterceptor.OnCreate()");
        //  sb.Append("     uri_android = ").AppendLine(uri_android.ToString());
        //  System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine(sb.ToString());
        //#endif

        // Convert iOS NSUrl to C#/netxf/BCL System.Uri - common API
        Uri uri_netfx = new Uri(uri_android.ToString());

        // load redirect_url Page
        AuthenticationState.Authenticator.OnPageLoading(uri_netfx);*/

        var uri = new Uri(Intent.Data.ToString());

        // Load redirectUrl page
        AuthenticationState.Authenticator.OnPageLoading(uri);

        this.Finish();

        return;
    }
}
```